# OpenGL 3D GUI Engine and/or assets

Tags: user-interface, opengl, 3d, assets

Are there any OpenGL 3D GUI libraries?

and/or

Are there any 3D assets like windows, list boxes, etc. that can be used in a 3D game engine?

Something like Age 3D is a great start, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cq8Qs8lqqFA, but they aren't around anymore.

Comment: Another interesting 3D GUI by c41xpl. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vlj1l17ltqk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [Crazy Eddie's GUI System](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)?

Comment: This looks really promising too. Thanks for the find!

Comment: No problem. I couldn't tell if you meant actual 3d components or if you meant a GUI engine that works in 3d games. ; )  It's fairly popular with the Ogre3d crowd, which is where I ran across it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/). Definitely still in development -- the most recent weekly snapshot was released today.

Comment: FLTK is looking really promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Qt allows all GUI elements to drawn into an OpenGL viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this: http://www.libnui.net/